# How to make large-scale shadow casting performant? (400x400 tilemap)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 2d, shadow, lighting

I am trying to achieve a day/night lighting system similar to the game RimWorld. A short preview of what I want can be seen here: https://giphy.com/gifs/VgzcwtjueP7BrYSrXe

During the daytime, the sun needs to cast shadows. At nighttime, all light sources need to cast shadows.

How can I cast shadows for objects in my world? There is a `ShadowCaster2D` component, but most of my shadow casting objects are tiles on a tilemap.

**The crucial part** - my tilemap is `400x400` in size. If there is a 1/10 chance of a tree spawning, that's between 10000-15000 trees, which need to individually cast shadows. Not to mention all the player-built terrain such as walls. Therefore, I'm not sure if I can use any "connect multiple colliders into one" type thing.

I've been able to add `ShadowCaster2D` to a `GameObject`, and then attach that `GameObject` to each individual tile (that needs to cast shadows, such as walls and trees), and it just seems to crush performance. (**>300 FPS to 4 FPS**)

1. Should I use the built-in `ShadowCaster2D` for this, or is there another way that is more performant?
2. Is this better done with some sort of shader magic (solution other than Unity's lighting system?)
3. Would somehow reducing the quality of the shadows and/or culling when the camera is zooming in/out help with performance?